# woocommerce single product not showing redirect to checkout, why?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

woocommerce single product not showing redirect to checkout, why? have anybody for help me??? I'm waiting for response.

you can check on, please go this url (http://yoonys33.sakura.ne.jp/jp/shop/ ) & view any product.

Comment: i visited webpage and it redirected to checkout after clicking image

Comment: can u have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I have fixed it. Now it stay on single product page. 
http://yoonys33.sakura.ne.jp/jp/product/app-development-package/